# AJAX routing is not working for my custom function in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, laravel-4

I am using **Laravel 4.2.6**

This is my function with an ajax call to the controller's method called **savesession**

```
function saveActualSession() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'savesession',
        data: {
            my_username: $('input#username').val()
        },
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            console.log("success");
        }
    });
}
```

In controller I have this:

```
public function savesession()
{
    if(Request::ajax())
    {
        $my_username = Input::post('my_username');
        if ($my_username) { Session::put('my_username', $my_username); }
        return $my_username;
    } 

}
```

Sessions saving is triggered like this on different places in my javascript code:

```
saveActualSession()
.done(function(e) {
    // Things to be done after saving session
})
.fail(function(e) {
    alert('oh no!')
});
```

The problem is that it's giving me this error in the console:

`"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://laravelsite.dev/savesession"`

It's weird because the url exists 100%, because when I try to do this in the controller:

```
public function savesession()
{
    if(Request::ajax())
    {
        $my_username = Input::post('my_username');
        if ($my_username) { Session::put('my_username', $my_username); }
        return $my_username;
    } 
    else 
    {
        print_r("url is working");
        die();
    }
}
```

and I access the url directly in my browser like:

```
http://laravelsite.dev/savesession
```

It's giving me the print_r message url is not working and it dies.

btw. my routes look like this:

```
Route::any('savesession', ['as' => 'savesession','uses' => 'RegistrationController@savesession']);
```

What am I doing wrong?

I have a similar AJAX function for getting sessions and that route works fine and no server errors are shown.

Any idea?

Comment: Input::post(...) ... i think you want Input::get(...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a wrong method there. Simply change...

```
$my_username = Input::post('my_username');
```

to this...

```
$my_username = Input::get('my_username');
```

Get does not refer to the HTTP Method in this context, it refers to what Laravel is doing - get an input value. This value can be GET or POST, it doesn't actually make a difference.